# Firebase deployed site will not open on mobile devices and other person's pc

Tags: reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

I just created an e-commerce site with ReactJS and I used Firebase for my database and hosting. I deployed the site and it loads on my pc, but not my mobile device or my friends' computers. I am not sure what the problem is. I tried redeploying the site also, but still no luck. I deployed another project recently this way and had no issues. I have included all the info from my terminal below. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
  Bens-MacBook-Pro:velo-e-commerce benharned$ sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
/usr/local/bin/firebase -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js
+ firebase-tools@6.2.2
updated 1 package in 3.074s
Bens-MacBook-Pro:velo-e-commerce ######$ firebase login
Already logged in as #######76@gmail.com
Bens-MacBook-Pro:velo-e-commerce #######$ firebase init

     ######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###     ######  ########
     ##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##
     ######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######
     ##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##
     ##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  /Users/#######/Documents/velo-e-commerce

Before we get started, keep in mind:

  * You are initializing in an existing Firebase project directory

? Which Firebase CLI features do you want to setup for this folder? Press Space 
to select features, then Enter to confirm your choices. Hosting: Configure and d
eploy Firebase Hosting sites

=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

i  .firebaserc already has a default project, skipping

=== Hosting Setup

Your public directory is the folder (relative to your project directory) that
will contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with firebase deploy. If you
have a build process for your assets, use your build's output directory.

? What do you want to use as your public directory? build
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
? File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of build/index.html

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

✔  Firebase initialization complete!
Bens-MacBook-Pro:velo-e-commerce benharned$ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'velo-velo'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (42.44 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting[velo-velo]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[velo-velo]: found 19 files in build
✔  hosting[velo-velo]: file upload complete
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function charge(us-central1)...
✔  functions[charge(us-central1)]: Successful update operation. 
i  hosting[velo-velo]: finalizing version...
✔  hosting[velo-velo]: version finalized
i  hosting[velo-velo]: releasing new version...
✔  hosting[velo-velo]: release complete

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/velo-velo/overview
Hosting URL: https://velo-velo.firebaseapp.com
Bens-MacBook-Pro:velo-e-commerce benharned$
```

Comment: this is too little information. see if there is error logs when you inspect the production site, if your build system is behaving as expected (i.e. copying relevant artifacts to the "public directory"), or something else. Also helps if you detail a little your build/deploy script.

Comment: Just edited the post and added the info from the terminal.

Comment: When I try to open the site on my mobile, I just get a white screen and no errors or anything.

Comment: If I check the JavaScript console of [your page](https://velo-velo.firebaseapp.com/), I  see a ton of error messages. You might want to check those out. To get more concrete help on the actual code causing the error, check out: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this is what i see when i inspect the page: https://imgur.com/a/C0TiZff so far my best guess is some issue with your build system. react tutorials instruct us to do one thing. firebase tutorials instruct us to do another. you need to assemble something in the middle. this is not the exact solution you need, but a good start. this sample repo might help you to assemble a build process good enough for development and production: https://github.com/sombriks/react-browserify-firebase

Comment: @Sombriks The imgur link will not open for some reason. When I open the app and open the Chrome developer tools I don't see the errors. I tried opening the app in Safari and I get the white screen. Is my pc opening it in some sort of special mode? Is this why I can't see the errors?

Comment: @frootloops had you better luck doing checkout on the sample project and trying to run it? you might have to change firebase project name in .firebaserc but it for sure will give you a goo point of comparison to your actual issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am not quite sure I understand. Do you mean just look at the project in dev mode and look for errors in the console? What do you mean by checkout the sample project and try to run it?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is some issue on build system; your 'dev' mode works fine, but 'publish/deploy' is lacking some detail.

Please take a look at [this sample repo](https://github.com/sombriks/react-browserify-firebase) to see if it helps you to build for production.